# C# - openfiledialog box freezes while selecting file from Windows Media Device

Tags: c#, windows, ipad, openfiledialog

I have a program where I use an openfiledialog box to select a file and add that path to a textbox.  I then further process that file.

The issue I'm having is when I select a file that is on a Windows media device, such as an iPAD. Because it doesn't use the standard windows path, it has to copy the file to a temp folder first.  I don't even have to code that in, it will just automatically copy it to my windows temp folder and then put that as the path to the file.

The problem I'm having is that it freezes the UI until the file is finished copying.

Is there a more graceful method I can use so that if I'm choosing a file from a Windows media device, I can get a popup box or something to say that it is copying the file rather than freezing the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a thread. After make a thread you should show opendialog 
Or use a Action.
Because if you show dialog in main thread, it will hold main thread.

```
 //1. Thread 
Thread openDialogthread = new Thread(Showdialog);
openDialogthread.Start();

void Showdialog()
{ // do popup dialog here }

//2. Action
if(this.invokeRequired)
{
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>     fileOpendialog.ShowDialog();));
}
```

Comment: That's no good at all. The modal FileOpenDialog does not freeze the app, but you can't do anything anymore! The FileOpenDialog is also freezing.